# C# inheritance multiple for different children

Tags: c#, inheritance, parent-child, abstract

i have an abstract model named `BetaModel` that inherit its parent `AlphaModel`. Then
I have a bunch of request models that inherit the `BetaModel` and therefore naturally inherit `AlphaModel`, However I have the other bunch of response models which have to inherit the fields of `BetaModel` and **do not** need the fields in `AlphaModel`.

[Note: `AlphaModel` and `BetaModel` only contain some plain fields]

What is the elegant way to have the response models inherit the `BetModel` but ignore the `AlphaModel`?

Is it OK to turn the `AlphaModel` becomes an Interface, so that it only implemented in all the request models but not the response models?

Comment: very much depends on the circumstances... what do these classes stand for?

Comment: What is in 'AlphaModel'? only method signatures? or contains any implementation for some methods?

Comment: Requests... these are plain datatransfer objects right?

Comment: BetaModel and AlphaModel only contain some fields, no method inside them

Comment: @Amigo, in that case you can make your abstract model as interface. Though I have seen in many places the interface and abstract class (without any implementation) are used interchangeably, there is a difference between them. With abstract class you are defining a "family" or "kind-of" hierarchy, but interfaces are just a contract that the inheritor is agreed to provide an implementation (i.e. the same interface can be implemented by multiple non-related classes as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are basically contradicting the description with the "desired" architecture.

Also, always bare in mind that you don't decide architecture based on results ("Is it OK to turn the AlphaModel becomes an Interface"): your decisions are based on needs and responsibilities.

**Interfaces**

Think of that as a contract the classes are agreeing with. They don't hold any implementations and solely describe one contract the class **implements**

**Abstract Classes**

They are... Classes. As such, they don't define a contract, they define behaviours. And mostly, when defining an abstract class, you are looking for a abstract behaviour that you want children classes to **inherit** and/or give meaning to.

**Your problem**

You are saying some classes must inherit from `AlphaModel` and some others must **NOT** inherit from `AlphaModel`.

Therefore, you are saying that:

- A certain class `BetaModel1` inherits from `AlphaModel` and introduces some new members functionality.
- Another class `BetaModel2` should not expose any member from `AlphaModel` (which screams it doesn't inherit from `AlphaModel`) but also introduces the same members/functionality of `BetaModel1`

In other words, you are saying with all capital letters that `BetaModel1` and `BetaModel2` DO NOT INHERIT FROM THE SAME CLASS `AlphaModel`.

Now, back to our initial discussion. C# does not allow multiple inheritance (which looks like what you want to do). But there are strategies either to minimise re-writing code **and/or** enforce some implementations.

So, the "enforcing of implementation" is basically saying "I want this class to NECESSARILY provide certain functionality". Well... You need an `interface` for that

**C#**

```
    public interface IBetaModel
    {
        string PropertyBeta { get; set; }
        string MethodBeta();
    }
```

There is also the `AlphaModel`

**C#**

```
    public class AlphaModel
    {
        public string PropertyAlpha { get; set; }

        public string MethodAlpha()
        {
            return "This is Alpha";
        }
    }
```

Now, your desired `BetaModel1` (as described above) is quite simply inheriting from `AlphaModel` and implementing `IBetaModel`

**C#**

```
    public class BetaModel1 : AlphaModel, IBetaModel
    {
        public string PropertyBeta { get; set; }
        public string MethodBeta()
        {
            return "This is Beta?";
        }
    }
```

`BetaModel2` it's just implementing `IBetaModel`, in which case:

**C#**

```
    public class BetaModel2 : IBetaModel
    {
        public string PropertyBeta { get; set; }
        public string MethodBeta()
        {
            return "This is Beta?";
        }
    }
```

The usage of the classes would be like:

**C#**

```
    public void DoStuffWith(IBetaModel betaModel)
    {
        betaModel.PropertyBeta = "WOW, it works";
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var betaModel1 = new BetaModel1();
        var betaModel2 = new BetaModel2();
        AlphaModel betaModel1_ = new BetaModel1();
        //AlphaModel betaModel2_ = new BetaModel2(); //won't compile

        betaModel1.PropertyAlpha = "Test";
        //betaModel2.PropertyAlpha = "Test"; //won't compile

        DoStuffWith(betaModel1); //great!!!
        DoStuffWith(betaModel2); //great too!!!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is only about data make every datapart an interface like...

```
public interface IAlphaModel
{
    string SomeField { get; set; }
}

public interface IBetaModel
{
    int AnotherField { get; set; }
}

public interface ISomeRequest : IAlphaModel, IBetaModel
{
    bool YetAnotherField { get; set; }

}

class SomeRequest : ISomeRequest
{
    public string SomeField { get; set; }
    public int AnotherField { get; set; }
    public bool YetAnotherField { get; set; }
}

public interface IAnotherRequest : IBetaModel
{
    long TheUltimateField { get; set; }

}

class AnotherRequest : IAnotherRequest
{
    public int AnotherField { get; set; }
    public long TheUltimateField { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

Of course you can have the interfaces have more than one member if they are tied logically together.